# Is the Dirichlet Eta Function or Alternate Series, at complex values, a single or multivalues function?

Tags: nt.number-theory

I still have great doubts with complex functions, specifically:

> Is the Dirichlet eta function a single- or multi-valued function ?

If somebody could help with an answer, I would be very grateful.

Comment: This should be on MSE. $\eta(s)$ is entire. ${}{}{}$

Comment: I agree with @reuns: the Dirichlet eta function is analytic (and single-valued) on $\mathbb{C}$, and this question is not of research level (so that it belongs to https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

> $\displaystyle\eta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} n^{-s}, \ \Re(s) > 0 \ $
>   is entire

$\sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^{n+1} = \frac{1+(-1)^{N+1}}{2}$ and summing by parts and the binomial series
$$\begin{eqnarray}\eta(s) &=& \lim_{N \to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^{n+1} n^{-s} \\ &=& \lim_{N \to \infty} N^{-s}\frac{1+(-1)^{N+1}}{2}+ \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1+(-1)^{n+1}}{2} (n^{-s}-(n+1)^{-s}) \\ &=& \frac{1}2(2-2^{-s}+ \sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} n^{-s}(1- \sum_{k=0}^\infty {-s \choose k} n^{-k}))\\
 &=& \frac12(2-2^{-s}+ \sum_{k=1}^\infty {-s \choose k}(1-\eta(s+k)))\end{eqnarray}$$
This last series being locallly uniformly convergent for every $s \in \mathbb{C}$

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in a comment, this is the Dedekind eta function, not the Dirichlet eta function....

$$
\eta(q) = q^{1/24}\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-q^n),\qquad |q|<1
$$
is not a single-valued function of $q$.  Was that the question?

$$
\eta(\tau) = e^{\pi i \tau/12}\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-e^{2\pi i n \tau}\right),\qquad \mathrm{Im}\;\tau > 0
$$
is a single-valued function of $\tau$.  Was that the question?

Comment: Perahps I am wrong. But considering domain of Eta as the Half Complex Plane with positive Real part only, may I say that at each point of this domain exist only one value, in Codomain of this function ?  (Even if is no possible, I would like to thank you, for previous answer). Fabrizio

Comment: For example I would like to know, if inside the "critical strip", (the part of Complex Plane with  0<Re(s)<1 ), Dirichlet Eta Function can be considered a single or a multivalues function.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar, your post is about the Dedekind eta function, not the Dirichlet eta function.